# Arduino Uno vs Arduino MKR1000 analogRead discrepancies

Tags: pwm, arduino-uno

I'm using an Arduino to control a BLDC motor connected with the motor driver. It is just a simple control which I'm using a PWM as a signal. Before this, I'm used Arduino Uno pin 5 to control BLDC motor, the analogue value starts from 80. Now, I'm changed to Arduino MKR1000 board with the same pin 5 to control BLDC motor. But, for MKR1000 to rotate the motor, analogue value start from 125. My question is, why two of this board using a different PWM value for rotating the BLDC motor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Adruino Uno is running off 5V, while the MKR1000 is 3.3V.  This means you need a bit more on-time to get the same power output.